# Error occurred when installing package 'ChatterBot'

Tags: python, pycharm, chatbot, status, chatterbot

### ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\PycharmProjects\tanmay\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.

-->

---

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\PycharmProjects\tanmay\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\PycharmProjects\tanmay\venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tanmay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qydxnp60\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Could you please add more details to your post like which commands you used and what is your python version?

Comment: im using Python3.7 with Pycharm. I'm not able to install ChatterBot package in my system . help me for that.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.7, and remember to check Add to PATH (Important). Then type "pip install ChatterBot==1.0.0" in your PyCharm terminal window.

Comment: yeah. My path one is a big issue . thank you!